# multiplication of a ring subsets

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring, $A,B$ subsets of $R$, and $a,b,a_i,b_i\in R$. Definte the multiplication $$AB:=\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i|a_i\in A,b_i\in B,n\ge1\}$$
>   In other words, $AB$ is the smallest subset of $(R,+)$ which contains $\{ab|a\in A,b\in B\}$ and which is closed under addiction.

when $A=\{a\}$
$$aB:=\{a\}B=\{\sum_{i=1}^sab_i|b_i\in B,s\ge1\}$$
similarly, when 
$B=\{b\}$
$$Ab:=A\{b\}=\{\sum_{i=1}^sa_ib|a_i\in A,s\ge1\}$$

Then my professor 
claimed that
"if $0\in B$, then 
$$\{a_1,...,a_s\}B=a_1B+...+a_sB$$

$$B\{a_1,...,a_t\}=Ba_1+...+Ba_t$$

what i don't understand is that why we need $0\in B$ and how to prove the above claim. This looks very trivial but I could not figure it out. Anyone can give me some hints? Thanks.

my thought is:
$$\{a_1,...,a_s\}B=\sum_{i_1=1}^{n_1}a_1b_{i_1}+...+\sum_{i_s=1}^{n_s}a_sb_{i_s}=a_1B+...+a_sB$$
What's wrong with my reasoning as i did not use the fact that $0\in B$?

Comment: I don’t see why either.... but it is early in the morning now...

Comment: @rschwieb while for me it is late in the evening. I am a bit sleepy while studying for an abstract algebra exam. you know, it is horrifying. I will add the full details from the notes. do check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use $0\in B$ to get $a_iB\subseteq a_1B+\dots +a_nB$, so that $a_ib\in a_1B+\dots +a_nB$ for every $b\in B$.

The other inclusion follows immediately from the definition of $\{a_1,\dots, a_n\} B$.

To get a counterexample, just consider $R=\Bbb Z,\ B=\{1\},\ a_i>0$ and $n\ge 2$. Then $a_i\in\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}B$ but every element of $a_1B+a_2B+\dots+a_nB$ is at least $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n\,>a_i$.

Comment: okay, I see. what is so significant of this? You have any examples to show this. I guess this is related to ideals, right?

Comment: i have edited the post and added my thought for the claim, i did not see why my proof is wrong. Could you kindly check, i am a bit lost. thanks.@Berci

Comment: I'm not sure why your equations would hold. However, check the case when $B=\{1\}$.

Comment: Since by definition AB is just a collection of finite sum of products of any element from A and any element from B. So you can always arrange them such that $a_1$ appears first, then $a_2$...Does that make sense? Sorry I understand this question is trivial but could not figure it out what is wrong.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but what if some $a_i$ is omitted?

Comment: that makes a lot of sense...i am so dumb.